# Hide Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType' when no data in database

Tags: python, django

I am having this issue where I get this error unless there are at least 2 lines of data in the database. Basically what I am doing is marking an item as refunded. I will aggregate all of the fields and then do the math.

If I do not have at least 2 lines of data in the database, I always get this error.

`unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'`

The specific line is throwing the error is:

`total_partial = 0 - total_p_r['refund_amount__sum']`

I am not understanding why I am getting NoneType when the default is set to zero on all lines of the models. The code is below.

**views.py**

```
def inventory_management_refund(request):
    inventory = Inventory.objects.filter(Q(status__contains='REFUNDED') | Q(status__contains='Partial Refund')).order_by('id')
        
    totals = Inventory.objects.filter(status__contains='REFUNDED').aggregate(
        Sum('paid'),
        Sum('soldprice'),
        Sum('shipcost'),
        )
        
    total_p_r = Inventory.objects.filter(status__contains='Partial Refund').aggregate(
        Sum('refund_amount')
        )

    total_full = 0 - totals['paid__sum'] - totals['soldprice__sum'] - totals['shipcost__sum']
    total_partial = 0 - total_p_r['refund_amount__sum']

    total_refund_loss = total_full + total_partial

    return render(request, 'inventory/refunds.html', {"inventory": inventory, "total_refund_loss": total_refund_loss})
```

**template.html**

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-center">Refunded Items</h1>
    <hr>
  </div>
  {% if inventory.count == 0 %}
  <h2 class="text-success text-center">There are currently no refunds!</h2>
  {% endif %}
    {% if inventory.count > 0 %}
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Product</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th class="invmanrow">Purchase Price</th>
           <th class="invmanrow">Sold Price</th>
           <th class="invmanrow">Ship Cost</th>
           <th class="invmanrow">Refund Amount</th>
           <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for inventory in inventory %}
      <tr>
       <td>{{inventory.product}}</td>
       <td>{{inventory.description}}</td>
       <td class="invmanrow">{{inventory.paid}}</td>
       <td class="invmanrow">{{inventory.soldprice}}</td>
       <td class="invmanrow">{{inventory.shipcost}}</td>
       {% if inventory.status == 'REFUNDED' %}
       <td>{{inventory.refund_loss}}</td>
       {% endif %}
       {% if inventory.status == 'Partial Refund' %}
       <td>-{{inventory.refund_amount}}</td>
       {% endif %}
       <td>{{inventory.status}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h2 class="text-center text-danger">Total Loss: {{total_refund_loss}}</h2>
  <p class="text-center">The above denotes the total amount of money lost from refunded items. Amount accounted for is the total paid, total sold and ship cost total for the product.</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    paid = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    soldprice = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    shipcost = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    refund_amount = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    @property
    def refund_loss(self):
            return 0 - self.paid - self.soldprice - self.shipcost
```

**How can I hide that error so that if there is no data, I do not get that error and just display the template as it should? Any and all help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use coalesce to prevent getting none values in your function
You can do it as follows:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce  # Importing the function
def inventory_management_refund(request):
    inventory = Inventory.objects.filter(Q(status__contains='REFUNDED') | Q(status__contains='Partial Refund')).order_by('id')

    totals = Inventory.objects.filter(status__contains='REFUNDED').aggregate(
        paid_t = Coalesce(Sum('paid'), 0),
        sold_t = Coalesce(Sum('soldprice'), 0),
        ship_t = Coalesce(Sum('shipcost'), 0),
    )

    total_p_r = Inventory.objects.filter(status__contains='Partial Refund').aggregate(
        ref_t=Coalesce(Sum('refund_amount'), 0)
    )

    total_full = 0 - totals['paid_t'] - totals['sold_t'] - totals['ship_t']
    total_partial = 0 - total_p_r['ref_t']

    total_refund_loss = total_full + total_partial

    return render(request, 'inventory/refunds.html', {"inventory": inventory, "total_refund_loss": total_refund_loss})
```

When using complex aggregates, you need to give them an alias, thus I have added the alias, `paid_t`, `sold_t`, `ship_t`, and `ref_t`. You can read more about the Coalesce function in the docs. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce)

Comment: I updated my code with your recommendations and it said that I needed an output field so I imported DecimalField as so 'from django.db.models import DecimalField'. I then set 'output_field=DecimalField' to totals and that did the trick. Thank you so much!